# python random choice choosing nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a method to generate random string that always starts with a character and has length of at minimum 1.

```
class Util:
    @staticmethod
    def get_random_name():
        N = r.randint(0, 5)
        return "".join(
            r.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.ascii_uppercase
            )
        ).join(
            r.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.ascii_uppercase
                + string.digits
            )
            for _ in range(N)
        )
```

Now when I do this:

```
for i in range(0,50):
    logging.debug(str(i)+" -- "+Util().get_random_name())
```

Some of them gives me empty string or sometimes it starts with number.

**What am I missing ?**

Check the log:
[image]

Comment: 1. Of course it will start with a number; the first part of the string is `str(i)`. 2. what do you expect to happen when the value chosen for `N` is equal to 0?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "must be of length or higher"?

Comment: In `a.join(b)`, `a` is used as the element ***between*** each `b`. It won't be the *first* character in the string. You probably mean `r.choice(...) + r.choice(...)`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel please check the question again, maybe you missed -- to I added a snap of my log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
import random
import string


def get_random_name(min_n=0, max_n=5):
    initial = random.choice(
        string.ascii_lowercase
        + string.ascii_uppercase
    )
    return initial + "".join(
        random.choice(
            string.ascii_lowercase
            + string.ascii_uppercase
            + string.digits
        )
        for _ in range(
            random.randint(min_n, max_n)
        )
    )


for x in range(10):
    print(x, get_random_name(max_n=x))
```

Output (e.g.):

```
0 z
1 cm
2 W
3 oku9
4 nh
5 Ul3
6 yNPH
7 Rw7hW0eW
8 qR
9 BYKaGyv
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the `join` function, which is for joining together multiple strings with some symbol. But what you really want is to *concatenate* strings which in Python is done using the `+` sign.

Let's look at the `join` function:

```
>>> '|'.join('abc')
'a|b|c'
```

Let's look at this output:

```
aHCHRH1H0
```

What happened here is that you generate the first letter `H` and then the string `aCR10`, which is correct. But then instead of `+` a join occurs:

```
>>> 'H'.join('aCR10')
'aHCHRH1H0'
```

---

Fixed version:

```
class Util:
    @staticmethod
    def get_random_name():
        N = r.randint(0, 5)
        return r.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.ascii_uppercase
        ) + ''.join(
            r.choice(
                string.ascii_lowercase
                + string.ascii_uppercase
                + string.digits
            )
            for _ in range(N)
        )
```